# How to get the current value of an input field with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I would like to get HTML of an editable `div`. It contains text and an `<input>` tag. See:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contentEditable="true">
  I want <input type="number" value="3"> candies.
</div>
```

My problem is `<input type="number" value="3">`. When I update the value of the input field, I still get the default value.

So how can I get the live value of the input field?

I am not NOT looking for the value of the input field. The output should be the full content of `div#content` as a string.

Comment: You don't use `innerHTML`, you use `value`.

Comment: const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('values');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);


function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the value of an input doesn't affect the `value` attribute in the HTML, because that's used for its default value, not the current value.

You'll need to merge the value of the input into the `innerHTML` of the DIV to get the result you want.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let html = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
  let value = document.getElementById('input').value;
  new_html = html.replace(/value="\d+"/, `value="${value}"`);
  console.log(new_html);
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contentEditable="true">
  I want <input type="number" value="3" id="input"> candies.
</div>
```

Comment: I am not looking for the value only. I want to get the full HTML of the `div`. This is why it has the `contentEditable` attribute. So the output that I expect should be the string `I want <input type="number" value="x"> candies.`.

Comment: Mixing a content-editable DIV with `<input>` is very strange. You'll need to combine them separately.

Comment: Although it is strange, the user should be able to add input field.s This is the goal.

Comment: When you edit a content-editable field, your changes are not parsed as HTML. So they can't add input fields.

Comment: If you try your code, you'll see that the input field isn't even included in the editable portion. You can only edit the text around it.

Comment: If it's not, so how comes that I can delete that field?

Comment: If you delete a selection surrounding it you can delete it. But you can't modify it directly.

Answer (score 2):

The *value* isn't part of the HTML.  It's a live property on the DOM.  You need to fetch the actual `<input>` element and observe its `value` property.

Instead of `getElementById`, use `querySelector` which takes a more robust selector to identify the target element.  In this case that target element is the `<input>` inside the `#content` element.  For example:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('#content input').value);
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contentEditable="true">
  I want <input type="number" value="3"> candies.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Barmar said the attribute will not be updated only the internal DOM Property.

But you can manual update it on change like this:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
   e.target.setAttribute('value', e.target.value);
});

document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contentEditable="true">
  I want <input type="number" value="3"> candies.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't just add another id tag to your input element, like `<input id="contentInput" type="number" value="3">`

and then grab the inner HTML with this Id